# How to stop submission and alert the user that less than 10 questions selected with JS

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

This particular page of my project displays a list of questions stored in a database. The user needs to select 10 questions and then click the button to take a quiz. I am able to limit the checkbox selection to 10 questions as well as ensure there are no fewer than 10 questions selected. If a user selected 5 questions, for example, an alert pops up informing the user that 10 questions need to be selected, but then the form directs to its "action" location. How can I stop the form from submitting if there are fewer than 10 questions selected? Here is my code...

```
<?php
    session_start();

    // Insert header
    if ('Header.php') {
        include 'Header.php';
    } else {
        echo "The file was not found";
    }

    // Define database info
    $username   = "";
    $password   = "";
    $servername = "localhost";

    // Connect to database and display all 
    // questions with check boxes to allow user
    // to select a max of 10 questions.
    try {
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername; dbname=Quizes", $username, $password);
        // Set the PDO error mode to exception
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        // Query to select all questions
        $sql_selectQuestions = "SELECT * FROM QuestionTable";
        $result_selectQuestions = $pdo->query($sql_selectQuestions);
        $questionList = $result_selectQuestions->fetchAll();


    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Question Selection</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        chkcontrol = function(j) {
            var total = 0;
            var questions = document.getElementsByName('questions[]');
            for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
                if (questions[i].checked) {
                    total = total + 1;
                }
                if (total > 10) {
                    alert("Please select only 10 questions");
                    questions[i].checked = false;
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        chkmin = function() {
            var total;
            var questions = document.getElementsByName('questions[]');
            for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
                if (questions[i].checked) {
                    total = total + 1;
                }
                if (total < 10) {
                    alert("Please select 10 questions");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php echo "<br />"; ?>
        <form id="questionselect" name="questions" action="ChooseQuizTime.php" method="post">
            <table border="2" style="margin:0 auto; padding:5px">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Question Number</th>
                        <th>Questions</th>
                        <th>Include in Quiz</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php 
                        // Print a row for each record in the returned query
                        foreach($questionList as $key => $row)
                        {
                            echo "
                                 <tr>
                                    <td style='text-align:left;'>$row[questionId]</td>
                                    <td style='text-align:left;'>$row[questionText]</td>
                                    <td style='text-align:center;'><input type='checkbox' name='questions[]' onclick='chkcontrol($count)' value='$row[questionId]' /></td>
                                 </tr>";
                        }
                    ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div align="center">
                <br />
                <input type="submit" value="Take Quiz" onclick="chkmin()" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with form's `onsubmit` property:

```
<form id="questionselect" name="questions" action="ChooseQuizTime.php" method="post" onsubmit="return chkmin($count);">
```

Comment: I haven't dabbled in pure JS in quite some time but shouldn't the `onsubmit` listener be on the `<form>` tag?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus - you're right, I think I'm sleepy - I've updated my answer. Thx for mentioning

Comment: Thank you, this works. I ended up needing to take the $count variable out, which wasn't necessary in the first place, and the code you suggested works perfectly now.

Comment: I realized it only worked because total was set to 0 at the beginning of the function. It is not actually counting my checkboxes.

Comment: The mechanism to prevent the form for submitting will work when you figure out the correct way to count the checkboxes. For that you'll have to create another question. Also, please accept my answer, so others will know that the question has a valid answer, even if the problem doesn't have a solution here.